# VB LINQ query Where clause * not working?

Tags: vb.net, linq, wildcard, where-clause

Here is a function I've setup with my query trying to retrieve specific information that a user may or may not enter into a couple text boxes. The user can put in a...

- company name
- clients first name
- techs first name

What I want is if the user does not put in anything in the textbox that the query will returns all fields like "*" I believe is what LINQ uses and SQL uses "%". I've tried both and cant figure out why I cant retrieve a certain company with all clients and all techs.

```
    Public Function SpecificQueryInvoices(ByVal Company As String, ByVal Clientname As String, ByVal techname As String)

    Dim specificQuerySetInformation = From invo In database.Invoices
                              Join orgs In database.Organizations
                              On orgs.OrgId Equals invo.OrgId
                              Join clien In database.Clients
                              On clien.ClientId Equals invo.ClientId
                              Join tec In database.Teches
                              On tec.TechId Equals invo.TechId
                              Order By invo.InvoiceId
                              Where orgs.OrgName.StartsWith(Company) And clien.FirstName.StartsWith(Clientname) And tec.FirstName.StartsWith(techname)
                              Select New With {.Company = orgs.OrgName, .Client = clien.FirstName, _
                                               .Tech = tec.FirstName, invo.Date, _
                              invo.Notes, invo.Parts, invo.Labor, invo.Mileage, invo.TotalCost, _
                              invo.InvoiceNumber}


    Return specificQuerySetInformation

End Function

    Private Sub btnFilter_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnFilter.Click

    Dim companyName As String
    Dim ClientFirstName As String
    Dim TechFirstName As String



    If txtCompany.Text = "" Then
        companyName = "*"
    Else
        companyName = txtCompany.Text
    End If

    If txtClientName.Text = "" Then
        ClientFirstName = "*"
    Else
        ClientFirstName = txtClientName.Text
    End If

    If txtTechName.Text = "" Then
        TechFirstName = "*"
    Else
        TechFirstName = txtTechName.Text
    End If


    DataGridView2.DataSource = SpecificQueryInvoices(companyName, ClientFirstName, TechFirstName)


    MsgBox("Filter requested")
End Sub
```

Comment: How can this code even compile, your Function declaration does not even have a return type specified?

Answer (score 1):

> I believe is what LINQ uses

You're wrong. LINQ does not use wildcards at all.

If you want to handle cases like "user has not entered value" just build your query dynamically, it's pretty easy, and don't try using wildcards. After all, it will make your search faster.